# Listing files older than X minutes using it with ls command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
if [[ $line == *SECURITYRPT*  &&  (((**If the file is older than 5minutes**))) ]]
then
     echo "$line"
else
     echo "file present not older than 2minutes"
fi
```

What condition to put after `&&` to list files older than 5 minutes?

Comment: `If the file is older than 5minutes` is usually hard to do - filesystems usually record modification times, but not creatiion times, you have to usually explicitly enable tracking "creation time" of files on a filesystem (if it's supported). But "file modified older then 5 minutes ago" is simple with find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command with the `-mmin` parameter:

This example finds all files in the current directory (and subdirectories) that are aged less than 5 minutes. You can remove the "-" to match your needs :)

```
find ./ -type f -mmin -5;
```

[manual page for `find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 1):

Create a reference file with date of 5 minutes ago with `touch`.

Then test the file is `-o`lder`t`han your reference file.

```sh
ageref="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -f -- "$ageref"' EXIT

if touch -d '-5mn' -- "$ageref" && [[ "$line" == SECURITYRPT && "$file" -ot "$ageref" ]]; then
 : # Do watever
fi
```

See `help test | grep -F -- '-ot'`:

> `FILE1 -ot FILE2`  True if file1 is older than file2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "older than 5 minutes" means "modified 5 (or more) minutes ago, in Linux using bash:

```
if (($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y "$file") > 300)); then
    echo "$file is older that five minutes"
fi
```

The condition is `(($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y "$file") > 300))` and that expression can be used in compound logical expressions.